# How to detect a special symbol in the TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display in a TextBox a series of numbers with some special symbols, which can show some more info, when mouse hovers over them.

For example, I put in TextBox something like this:

> Value: 45*, 35,21 21,34

And when the user moves the mouse over the '*' symbol, a small window will appear with some text.

Is this possible? I'm little confused how to make this...In fact, something like hyperlink in text maybe helpful too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GetCharFromPosition function to determine which character the mouse is over:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
Char lastChar = ' ';

void textBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  char c = textBox1.GetCharFromPosition(e.Location);
  if (c.Equals('*')) {
    if (!c.Equals(lastChar)) {
      lastChar = c;
      tt.Show("This is something special", this.textBox1,
              new Point(e.Location.X + 20, e.Location.Y + 20),
              2000);
    }
  } else {
    lastChar = ' ';
    tt.Hide(this.textBox1);
  }
}
```